# C++ Open software with argument

Tags: c++

I search a lot but don't find nothing.

I want make a C++ software to run a software with argument in C++

Example : start putty -ssh user@server -pw password

start notepad -someargument

Comment: in your main function the `(int argc, char* argv[])` is how you pass in runtime arguments to software. i.e. `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { std::cerr << "Hello " << arg[0]}` if you run `yourexe.exe test1234` you would recieve the output `Hello test1234`

Comment: [link for your sprog](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DEN36Up4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a different software than your own program (with or without arguments) you can use [system()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) from `<cstdlib>` header.

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  system("start putty -ssh user@server -pw password");
  return 0;
}
```

If you want to evaluate the arguments to your own program, you can use `argv[]`. `argv[0]` holds the name/path of your program, and `argv[1] ... argv[argc-1]` the actual arguments i.e.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if ((argc > 1) && (!strcmp(argv[1], "-help"))) {
    std::cout << "Showing help" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works , but this work with this ?

L2.bin IP=0*0*0*0

I tryed but without success , what compiler you recomend ?

Comment: @OsniPezziniJunior This is portable and will work on any C++ compiler - I'm using "MS Visual Studio 2015", but gcc & clang will both compile this fine too. Which compiler you use and which error message does it output?